# How do I supply an API token to the GitLab Terraform provider as a Terraform secret resource?

Tags: terraform, credentials, terraform-provider-gitlab, terraform-provider-secrets

I am trying to use Terraform to manage some GitLab (self-hosted) configuration.  The Terraform GitLab provider requires a GitLab Personal Access Token to be able to make API calls to read and write the configuration.  When I try to provide this token using a Terraform `secret_resource` Terraform is unable to let me manage the secret.  When I try to import the secret, Terraform fails:

```
$ terraform import secret_resource.api_token "xxx"                                                                                        
secret_resource.api_token: Importing from ID "xxx"...
secret_resource.api_token: Import prepared!
  Prepared secret_resource for import
secret_resource.api_token: Refreshing state... [id=-]

Error: GET https://gitlab.example.com./api/v4/user/api/v4/user: 404 {error: 404 Not Found}

  on /path/to/providers.tf line 24, in provider "gitlab":                                                                                                          
  24: provider "gitlab" {
```

Here is the minimal Terraform that reproduces this behavior:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.13.6"                                                                                     

  required_providers {
    gitlab = {
      source = "nixpkgs/gitlab"
      version = "> 3.4.99"                                                                                           
    }
    secret = {
      source = "nixpkgs/secret"
      version = "~> 1.1"                                                                                             
      alias = "default"                                                                                              
    }
  }
}

resource "secret_resource" "api_token" {                                                                             
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

provider "gitlab" {                                                                                                  
  base_url = "https://gitlab.example.com./api/v4/user"                                             
  token = secret_resource.api_token.value                                                                            
}

resource "gitlab_project" "foo" {
    name = "foo"
}
```

I've omitted the real hostname and GitLab token value.  I can reliably reproduce this failure by initializing a new Terraform root module with this configuration and then trying to import the secret.

This seems like an unreasonable failure - `secret_resource` does not depend on the GitLab provider.  If Terraform let the value be imported then it would be available and then the GitLab provider would be properly configured.

I observe this behavior with:

- Terraform v0.13.6

  - provider registry.terraform.io/nixpkgs/gitlab v3.4.999 (git rev 68c8c0e4cf14fda698bcacb74cb01fcfe7128815)
  - provider registry.terraform.io/nixpkgs/secret v1.1.1

I would like to be able to continue to use `secret_resource` to manage the GitLab API token.  How can I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the error message, it seems like the `base_url` is incorrectly configured. `/api/v4/user` comes up twice:

```
Error: GET https://gitlab.example.com./api/v4/user/api/v4/user: 404 {error: 404 Not Found}
```

Try setting the `base_url` to just the hostname, with a slash:

```
provider "gitlab" {                                                                                                  
  base_url = "https://gitlab.example.com/"                                             
  token = secret_resource.api_token.value                                                                            
}
```

Comment: Great catch.  This seems like a real bug that I introduced while trying to minimize my example. :/  This might nevertheless be the best answer to the question as asked.  I want to dig a little deeper before deciding.  Either way, thanks for this.

Comment: Is your original problem solved? If not, maybe you can update the question.

Comment: It's not really.  I was thinking about posting a new question with corrected details but then I found the Terraform docs that basically say what I want is impossible.  So I changed what I want, for now (which is suboptimal) and I'll revisit all of this later, maybe after Terraform has gotten better.

Answer (score 0):

You also have a dot in address (`gitlab.example.com.`) which should rather be `gitlab.example.com`.

Comment: http://www.dns-sd.org/TrailingDotsInDomainNames.html